# How can i change chunk.css files name in every build?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, build, csp-html-webpack-plugin

I need change css files name every build. For this I created unicName variable depend time. And I want to change build chunk files name (js and css). I achieved chunk.js files name. But I can't change css files name. How can I change chunk.css files name every build? My target path build/static/css/ (chunk.css files)

```
 const { override } = require('customize-cra');
const path = require('path');
const cspHtmlWebpackPlugin = require("csp-html-webpack-plugin");
let date = new Date();
const unicName = date.getDay().toString() + date.getHours().toString() + date.getMinutes().toString() + date.getMilliseconds().toString();



const cspConfigPolicy = {
  ***** my csp configs **** 
};

function addCspHtmlWebpackPlugin(config) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        config.plugins.push(new cspHtmlWebpackPlugin(cspConfigPolicy));
    }

    return config;
}

const publicPathPlugin = (config, env) => {
    config.output = {
        filename: `[name].${unicName}.js`,
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        publicPath: '/',
        chunkFilename: `static/js/[name].${unicName}.chunk.js`,
    }
    return config;
}

module.exports = {
    webpack: override(addCspHtmlWebpackPlugin, publicPathPlugin),
};
```

I try Harshal Patil answer. But I got double chunk files. File created with both unique name and old name. How can I get only unic name chunk.css file?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things in your code. When using `create-react-app` and the wrapper `customize-cra` on top it, it should automatically produce unique names for you when compiling for production. Look at the original webpack configuration [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js). Notice the `config.output.filename` and `config.output.chunkFilename` configuration:

```js
return {
  output: {
    filename: isEnvProduction
      ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
      : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js',
      // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
    
    chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
      ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js'
      : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
  },
  // ... rest of the configuration
}
```

Same goes for CSS file generation which is done using [`mini-css-extract-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mini-css-extract-plugin). In the same file, the configuration for it is this:

```js
return {
  plugins: [
    // other plugins
    isEnvProduction &&
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
        // both options are optional
        filename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
        chunkFilename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css',
      }),
    // other plugins
  ]
  // ... rest of the configuration
}
```

In development mode, you don't need to worry as webpack-dev-server would handle in-memory generation of these files with HMR where appropriate and live-sync otherwise.

In production mode, it is automatically generated for you be the default configuration. The use of `[contenthash:8]` in `filename` and `chunkFilename` substitution will add a unique hash based on the content of an asset **giving you unique name automatically**. When the asset's content changes, [contenthash] will change as well.

That also means that you don't need `unicName` variable that you created in your code (That's probably an anti-pattern).

**The only thing you need to do is that you are properly setting the environment variable to development (using `npm start`) or production (`npm run build`).**

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. you are right about unicName. I will change it. As you said, when I got the build, double css files were created. I am sending the photo of the error as a comment.

Comment: @Ali, The two file that are getting generated are the generated file i.e. `[hash].chunk.css` and the source map file `[hash].chuck.css.map` file. The source map file is required for effective debugging. Simply ignore the `map` file or disable the sourcemap generation.

Comment: The files I mentioned are except for the map.css file. I sent files photo to the question section. You can see. I am getting 2 chunk.css and 2 chunk.map.css files.

Comment: @Ali, Sorry I don't understand your exact question or the issue. It is okay for chuck to be generated as it is a result of code splitting done by webpack to reduce your initial application loading time. Do you not want the chuck files?

Comment: @Harshai I had 40 css files before I used MiniCssExtractPlugin. But after using the MiniCssExtractPlugin plugin you mentioned, I got 80 css files. My previous 40 css files are still there and 40 unicName css files came on it. How do I prevent my previous 40 css files from being produced? "11524139" my unic name. Css files that don't include this number in their name are my first files.  How do I prevent my first files from generating?

Comment: @Ali, when you say that you are using `MiniCssExtractPlugin`, if you are literally using it, then stop using it. It is automatically added for you in the default `create-react-app` configuration, You don't need to add another plugin.

Comment: @Harshai  If I stop using MiniCssExtractPlugin how will I have unic named css files during every build?

Comment: That's the point. You should not use your custom `unic name`. That's what I said by anti-pattern. Your unique name would be automatically generated by the create-react-app. If you really intend to use your own unique naming strategy, then you should override the configuration by searching in plugins array and then modifying the extract css configuration in place.